# Hover issue with absolute positioned element

Tags: jquery, html

I have the following div:

```
<div class="red"></div>
```

When it is hovered a button is created dynamically and appended to the `body` via jQuery and on mouse leave the button is removed from `body`.

```
var $button = $("<button>").html("Hover me");

$(".red").on("mouseenter", function () {

    var $bClone = $button.clone(),
        $this = $(this);

    $bClone.css({
        position: "absolute",
        left: $this.offset().left,
        top: $this.offset().top
    });

    $this.data("button", $bClone);

    $("body").append($bClone);
}).on("mouseleave", function () {

    var $this = $(this),
        $button = $this.data("button");

    if ($this.data("button")) {
        $button.remove();    
    }
});
```

The problem is that when I hover the button that appears when `.red` is hovered the button is removed.

I tried to fix the problem using `:not(.red)` as the second parameter of `on` function, but still it doesn't work.

How can this problem be fixed?

[**JSFIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/pPVA9/)

Comment: why can't you place the button inside the `red` element with relative position

Comment: @ArunPJohny Because I want the `.red` HTML to remain intact.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this in your **mouseleave** event:

```
$('body').on("mouseleave", '.red, button', function (e) {

    var o = $(".red").offset();
    var w = $(".red").width();
    var h = $(".red").height();

    if ((e.pageX < o.left || e.pageX > o.left + w) ||
        (e.pageY < o.top || e.pageY > o.top + h)) {
        $("button").remove();
    }

});
```

The **button** will be removed only if the cursor position is not whitin the **.red div**.

Here is the jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/caA5b/3/

Comment: I replaced `.possition()` with `.offset()`. It seems that `.position()` doesn't work in other cases, but `offset` does.

Comment: Good catch! *position()* gets the current element coordinates relative to the offset parent, while *offset()* gets the current element coordinates relative to the document. I updated my answer to use *offset()*. Thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

It seems like your div remains empty. So, instead of $("body").append($bClone); use $(".red").append($bClone); Hope this will help

Answer (score 0):

I made some changes in your fiddle so i found the result you want so what i  did i remove the position absolute and put button in to div like this

```
var $button = $("<button>").html("Hover me");

$(".red, .red button").on("mouseenter", function () {

var $bClone = $button.clone(),
    $this = $(this);

$bClone.css({
    left: $this.offset().left,
    top: $this.offset().top
});

$this.data("button", $bClone);

$("body .red").append($bClone);
}).on("mouseleave", function () {

var $this = $(this),
    $button = $this.data("button");

if ($this.data("button")) {
    $button.remove();    
}
});
```

just copy past this code in your fiddle and see the result